# What is meant by groupid and artifactid?

Tags: maven

I learned about the usage of pom.xml. But I couldn't figure out what is meant by `groupId` and `artifactId` in the below code:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You have to read the introduction of maven. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html This is not spring specific

Answer (score 0):

These ids make up your artifact's coordinates (together with version, type and classifier). This is necessary to identify the artifact you want to include as a dependency in your project. The artifact is then fetched from your local or a remote repository and will be added to your project's classpath.